# Realtime Plotting using CorePlot dependent upon User Selection

Tags: iphone, xcode, multithreading, core-plot

I have a view controller with a tableView at the top and a scrollView underneath that allows the user to scroll through graphs. (i tried to submit a picture of it but was denied due to my reputation).

How would I set it up so that the user can select different combinations of tableCells and the graph would draw depending upon the user selection of dates from the tableview in real time.

I understand that you shouldn't run the UI on anything other than the main thread and that you shouldn't run core plot on a separate thread. As the data may take some time to load and the graphs will take some time to draw (especially with increasing numbers of selection) i need a spinning wheel in the graph and for it to generate whilst the user can keep scrolling through the tableView.

Perhaps calling [graph reloadData] when the data model changes, however I am still at a loss on how to integrate it! :/

I'm hoping to develop a UI with a similar elegance and functionality to the 'Stocks' app that comes preloaded on the iPhone.

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to do this it would be very much appreciated!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-reloadData` method (for individual plots or the whole graph) is the way to go. Make sure you call it from the main thread and don't call it until the datasource is ready to provide the new data.

The *StockPlot* example app included with Core Plot uses `NSURLConnection` to load data from the web. That example and the "Real-Time Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* example app show different ways of updating the plot data over time.

Comment: Thankyou very much for that help - ill go and look at how they achieve this!